# Total days from two dates in mysql

Tags: mysql, datediff

For the leave application, FROM date and TO date is given by selecting the dates from calender. I have these two dates in mysql.I want to calculate number of days for the leave. So Person applying leave from July 1 to July 5 th. So total 5 days.
But when i use DateDiff(to, date) it gives 4.
How can i get 5 days?

```
select datediff('2015-07-05','2015-07-01');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply do `+1`, as you already notice, `DATEDIFF` excludes starting date, see example below:

```
select (datediff('2015-07-05','2015-07-01') + 1) as days
```

Answer (score 0):

**DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2)**

DATEDIFF() returns expr1 − expr2 expressed as a value in days from one date to the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time expressions. Only the date parts of the values are used in the calculation.

example

```
 SELECT DATEDIFF('2007-12-31 23:59:59','2007-12-30');
 output : 1
```

or

```
 SELECT DATEDIFF('2010-11-30 23:59:59','2010-12-31');
 Output : 31
```

You can add manual plus 1

Answer (score 0):

If you closely look at datediff function,

when you use two same dates, it will give you 0 days as a difference, not 1.

```
select datediff('2015-07-01','2015-07-01');
```

Will give you 0 days.

So its obvious that you will get one less day as it starts with 0 difference for same date.

Answer (score 0):

`datediff` will return difference between two dates however you need to include both the dates while calculating the number of leaves. You should use `value returned from datediff` + 1.